# Looping through a multi-dimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to test each 'voucher' in a multi-dimensional array and I was advised that the best way to do this is the foreach loop. However, I'm not sure how to use $key and $value in order to access the vouchers.

This is how the array looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxbSX.jpg

```
foreach($allVouchers as $key => $value){
        $signIn = curl_init();
        $voucherURL = 'https://splash-static.ironwifi.com/radius_test.php?ip=' . $ip . '&backup_ip=' . $backupIP . '&auth_port=' . $port . '&secret=' . $secret . '&username=' . $allVouchers["_embedded"]["vouchers"][$key]['code'] . '&password=' . $allVouchers["_embedded"]["vouchers"][$key]['code'] . '&c=*cachebuster*&nas_ip=19.29.39.49';
        curl_setopt($signIn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($signIn, CURLOPT_URL, $voucherURL);
        $access = curl_exec($signIn);
        curl_close($signIn);
        $accessArray = json_decode($access, true);
                print_r($accessArray);

    }
```

This is the output of var_dump:

```
    array(
9
) {
[0]=> array(
6
) {
[\"_links\"]=> array(
4
) {
[\"self\"]=> array(
1
) {
[\"href\"]=> string(
70
) \"https://europe-west2.ironwifi.com/api/67ec3855dc288c4f/vouchers?page=1\" }
[\"first\"]=> array(
1
) {
[\"href\"]=> string(
63
) \"https://europe-west2.ironwifi.com/api/67ec3855dc288c4f/vouchers\" }
[\"last\"]=> array(
1
) {
[\"href\"]=> string(
70
) \"https://europe-west2.ironwifi.com/api/67ec3855dc288c4f/vouchers?page=9\" }
[\"next\"]=> array(
1
) {
[\"href\"]=> string(
70
) \"https://europe-west2.ironwifi.com/api/67ec3855dc288c4f/vouchers?page=2\" } }
[\"_embedded\"]=> array(
1
) {
[\"vouchers\"]=> array(
25
) {
[0]=> array(
8
) {
[\"id\"]=> string(
32
) \"secret id\"
[\"code\"]=> string(
7
) \"mntvre7\"
[\"username\"]=> string(
7
```

Comment: write the output of this command: var_dump($allVouchers);

Comment: There's output of print_r($allVouchers) when you click on the imgur link. But I will post var_dump as well.

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/0CmkaEp

Comment: Please don't post links to images of data, add the text to the question.

Comment: Right, I apologize. The post has been edited, although that is not the whole array since it is too long.

Comment: If you use var_export (instead of var_dump), for your input data array it makes it easier for us to play with the data.  Try also adding your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I think is a similar minimal data structure that is equivalent to yours:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        '_links' =>
        [
        ],
        '_embedded' =>
        [
            'vouchers' =>
            [
                [
                    'code' => 23
                ],
                [
                    'code' => 47
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($data as $item) {
    foreach($item['_embedded']['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
        echo $voucher['code'], "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
23
47
```